# How can I bring a date picker inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

The date picker and text box looks like this

[image]

The code is given below :

```
<html:text name="facultyAchievementsForm" property="studentAchivementsDate" readonly="true" styleId="studentAchivements13"></html:text>
    <script language="JavaScript"> new tcal({ 
                                        'formname'    : 'facultyAchievementsForm', 
                                        'controlname' : 'studentAchivements13' 
                                           });
    </script>
```

I want the date picker to come inside of the textbox, what should I do?

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly the HTML result of your code, but based on the image you posted, it seems that you have 3 elements inside 2 table columns :

A label (Date:) inside the left cell
A textbox and an icon of a calendar inside the right cell

The HTML result will be something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><label></label></td>
<td class="calendar"><input><img></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can use some CSS to place the img tag inside the textbox.

You can set the img tag position **absolute** and you use **top**, **left** properties.

Here is an example :

```css
td {
  position:relative;
  }
td.calendar input {
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
 }
 td.calendar img {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  left:174px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Date:</label></td>
<td class="calendar"><input><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAWElEQVRYhe3SQQoAIAhE0bn/pW3VIqGCUEZpPrgS4S0E1D5zE72vC/CH0VMXYABs5g99r/sTpBYgKwH6AOhPKAAdkJUAfQD0JxSADshKgNKABZI41+iAvxpNfqDCtdHKkAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest solution:**

Use [Date Picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [JQuery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {    
            $(".datePicker").datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" class="datePicker" />
```

Comment: **@Syed Noman** I tried it but only a text area is coming and nothing is happening on mouse events.

Comment: Don't forget to add a JQuery UI reference in your code or it will not work.

Comment: I've never used jquery so sorry **@Sylvain B** I just didn't get what is JQuey UI reference. Is that the code what we write in the head tag?

Comment: You can find all the documentation of JQuery UI at this URL jqueryui.com. If you prefer not using JQuery UI, you can just use CSS. Take a look at my other answer for an example.